# Disposing the BindingSource of a ComboBox is extremely slow...

Tags: performance, datagridview, combobox, dispose, bindingsource

I have a main table with 4 lookup tables. All tables are bound to SQL tables accessed via stored procedures. Each lookup table has between 3 and 27 rows. The main table has about 22,000 rows (pet food & products).

My DataGridView displays rows of the main table with the lookup columns configured as ComboBoxes. I can insert, delete, edit the main table, ... all of these functions work fine. The initial loading of the form and inserting a new row each take about a second but this is not concerning. All other operations are relatively fast.

[Here is a screen shot of the DataGridView:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OkVpz.png)

The problem comes when I close the form...and only after having inserted one or more rows into the main table. The closing of the form can take up to a minute. In the closing of the form I now dispose of the binding sources for the 5 tables myself so that I can time them. Disposing of the binding source for the 4 lookup tables routinely takes 10-15 seconds per table. Closing the binding source for the main table takes no time at all. Again, this only happens after inserting a new row into the main table. I can edit main table rows, change lookup column values, and delete rows and closing the form in those use cases is instant.

I have tried running the program within VS, outside of VS running a debug EXE, and running outside of VS running a release version of the EXE, all with similar results.

What can I do to prevent this long delay disposing of the ComboBox binding sources? Is this typical and are there alternatives I should be considering?

Comment: Hey, what am I missing? My question gets down-voted by someone who doesn't take the time to provide any comment/feedback? That is not very helpful. Please, if there is something off about my question, let me know, I can't make it better without knowing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After three days of pounding my head against the wall trying all kinds of unsuccessful resolutions, I rebuilt the application from scratch. That fixed the problem and I believe I discovered the cause. At first I just created the data set with all the table adapters, which was pretty fast, and then I added a single form and grid to mimic the condition I described above above. Testing confirmed no issues at all so I continued added more forms with the same ComboBox look-ups and it continues to work fine. I am pretty sure that there was something screwy in the data set definitions I had previously. Hopefully this helps someone in the future.